# Laravel Excel export with header that combine column

Tags: excel, laravel, header, export

I am very new to laravel. I need help on excel export in laravel. I need to make a header like in the image attached. How can I combine column for the header and that header will take the total size of column below it?

For example in the image below, first row of months will be a loop and get data from months table in database. Second row is some data from the dropdown on form in blade page that will loop too but will be the same and loop for 12 times. Both row will start at column D onwards to the right.

How can I achieve that first 2 row of header like in the image? Where do I need to custom it ? In export or in controller and how?

[header with combine column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3l46.png)

I already tried and get the result like in the image attached. I manage to get result for row A to Z2 along with its data below it. But I dont know how to custom that 2 row header above it. I need that 2 row header to combine column and take the size of total column corresponding row below it.

Comment: Are you using any package for the Excel export? Can you share some code sample?

Comment: @tamrat im using maatwebsite package for excel